# How to reference JSON list value with a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to do this:

```
JSON_VALUE(@jsondata, CONCAT('$.[', @count, '].Name')
```

such that I can reference a value in my json list using a variable, however the JSON_VALUE function requires a string literal for the 2nd argument (JSON Path).

Is there a way to either make the function read a string as a string literal, or another way to reference a list with a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address a list with a variable by destructuring it into a table using `OPENJSON`.

For example, given:

```
declare @jsondata nvarchar(max) = '[
{"Name":"zero","Value":"cero"}, 
{"Name":"one","Value":"uno"}, 
{"Name":"two","Value":"dos"}, 
{"Name":"three","Value":"tres"} 
]'

declare @count int set @count = 1
declare @val nvarchar(50) 
set @val = (select JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Name') from OPENJSON(@JsonData) d where d."key" = @count)
select @count, @val
```

For a more advanced method you can query JSON with a schema that describes the structure and elements you are interested in:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-an-explicit-schema-sql-server